# React: Browser donot load the page by self until i refresh the page

Tags: reactjs

Actually, the problem is when I click on the link the browser don't get the page automatically I always need to refresh then it loads that page, I am new in react so is anyone know how I can rid of this. Thanks in advance
here is my navigation bar code

```
function MainNavigation() {
  return (
      <BrowserRouter>
    <header>
      <div>React Meets Up</div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">AllMeetUp</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/newmeetup">New MeetUp</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/favorites">Favourite Page</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
export default MainNavigation;
```

here is my app.js code

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import MainNavigation from "./components/Layout/MainNavigation";
import AllMeetsUpPage from "./Pages/AllMeetUp";
import FavouritesPage from "./Pages/Favourite";
import NewMeetUpPage from "./Pages/NewMeetUp";
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
     <MainNavigation />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<AllMeetsUpPage />} />
        <Route path="/newmeetup" element={<NewMeetUpPage />} />
        <Route path="/favorites" element={<FavouritesPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and finally here is my index.js code

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App.js";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
  <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you do `<Route path="/" element={<AllMeetsUpPage />} />` instead of `<Route path="/"><AllMeetsUpPage /></Route>`?

Comment: it's because i am using v6 of react-router-dom

Comment: Oh, that explains a lot. Then my advice is probably incorrect.

Comment: I was not aware that there even was a v6 of react-router-dom. It was apparently released a couple of weeks ago. In any case, I still don't see why you use BrowserRouter within MainNavigation.

Comment: your code works thankyou i uninstall and install the v5.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem by uninstalling the react-router-dom first and then install v5.2.0
I also remove the browser routing tag at the main navigation